# SES Identity status is still verification pending after 72 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am new to dealing with identity verification in SES. I asked the client to publish the CNAME records listed from SES which they already did last Friday. As far as I understood, it will take about 72 hours for the status to be updated to verified. However, after 72 hours, it is still in "Verification pending" status.

Just a note, that earlier today, the status became "Expired" (or was it Failed) so I had to click "Retry" and the status became "Verification pending" again.

**Question:**

Do I understand it correct that after the client published the CNAME records to their DNS provider, the record starts to be propagated within 72 hours? And by the time, I clicked "Retry", does that resets back to 72 hours?

What I tried

- Created an domain identity
- Added SES CNAME records to the DNS provider
- Waited for 3 days

What was expected:

- The identity status to be "Verified"

The actual result:

- The identity status is still "Verification pending" after 3 days

Comment: I'm not sure your client has added the `TXT` record correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do is to check if such CNAME entries have been added or not to their domain
you can use an online tool like "https://mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx" and then check for the records given to you by the SES verified domains tab in AWS console.